# Gravity Collider Bone Physics does not work when cube is hidden

Tags: bones, physics

Gravity Collider Bone Physics
https://modelinghappy.com/archives/43818
I added physics to this add-on to show the cube and weight paint on it, but when I export with the cube shown, the cube appears and seems to reflect it.
If I hide the Armature_bone physics layer, physics and weight paint don't seem to work. Is there any way to hide the cube and have it reflect?
I can't put my model in the photo so I have to replace it with another model.
[image]